# Access DLookup multiple criteria with Boolean

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a vba statement with the below DLookup in - it has multiple criteria - [ID] is integer and the [Search] field is a YES\NO boolean field.  However, this does not work:

```
DLookup("ImageFolder", "qryMasterImageFolders", "ID=1 AND [Search] = True")
```

I have also tried the below to no avail:

```
DLookup("ImageFolder", "qryMasterImageFolders", "ID=1 AND [Search] <> NULL")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"[ID]=1 AND [Search]=True"`? I don't know if it's enough to fix it, but it'll probably be better

Comment: If I do that I receive the message: Invalid use of Null

Comment: O_o : Strange as we didn't use `NULL`, is `ID` a field in your table?

Comment: Yes, ID is the PK

Comment: You receive error message about invalid use of Null because you are trying to assign results of DLookup to string value, you didn't show whole code line. DLookup returns Null if it doesn't find the data. Use Nz function before assigning and check your  qryMasterImageFolders if it returns rows with `ID=1 AND [Search] = True` criteria, it should work

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I'm now checking the DLookup first for NULL and I get the result I want.

Comment: One more thing: don't use "[Search] <> NULL" because nothing is ever equal to or not equal to NULL. If you make a comparison to NULL, you will get a NULL result, not true or false. Instead you should say "[Search] IS NOT NULL".